# In Chrome, SVG elements constructed too far off-screen do not render when brought into view

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, svg

I am creating a web-site that drives content for a large 2D area off a CMS, so I have a system that runs on a timer, examines the part of the area that is currently on-screen, and loads content that is close enough to the view area that it might soon come into view.

This all seems to work quite nicely, apart from one small glitch.

Some of my content is SVG elements created procedurally via JS (the load mechanism feeds data from the CMS into JS functions, which create the using document.createElementNS and insert it into a div in the correct absolute position).

This content appears fine if is on-screen at the time it is loaded (this happens when the page is initially loaded).

And it also appears if it loaded while an animation is moving the visible area (animation is used to follow paths across the 2D space).

HOWEVER, if I am manually moving the visible area (which I have implemented via click+drag) then the SVG elements are added to the document tree, but when they come into view they do not render.

If I do something to "nudge" the renderer, such as hiding an unrelated element via DevTools, or resizing the window slightly, then they appear.

I am thinking this may be a bug in Chrome?  e.g. where it has initially decided the elements need not be drawn and does not reprocess correctly when that needs reconsideration?  Or maybe I am missing something, I am only semi-experienced in manipulating HTML documents via JS (but after a quick look I do not see the same behaviour in firefox...)

I am moving the visible area by changing the (left, top) of a parent element (I do not want to use scrolling for that as the size of the 2D space is not defined in advance...)

Otherwise, is there some way I could trick the browser into recalculating what should be drawn?  I was wondering about having a small transparent element on screen that I show and hide on a timer, although a workaround that prevents the problem in the first place would be preferable...

Thanks for any advice!

Ian

p.s. I cannot instantly produce demo code for this as the code-base is moderately large, but I will spend time to make a simpler example if that proves necessary...

Comment: Setting a 1px square invisible element with static positioning that continually cycles hidden and shown does make the missing elements appear, although they can now pop-up because they only appear when the invisible element timer cycles _and_ the element is now on-screen, so I need to set the timer really fast to make minimise that, which is not ideal...

Comment: Set the content to display:none and back again perhaps.

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't seem to be that simple, if I hide/show just the SVG then the graphical elements within it do not appear.

If I recurse into the SVG's children then (it's difficult to be precise but it looks like) those that are on-screen at the moment I show them are rendered, those that were still off screen at that moment are not...

I suppose I could store the bounds of the children and watch for when I should turn them on, but I still wonder where that would work if they don't reach the corners of their rectangle...?

Comment: Ah, here's a neater hack, if I only toggle my invisible 1x1 div while scrolling, at least that's not running all the time...